# save the zipped file to the same directory

Tags: c#, zip, permission-denied, dotnetzip

I have a question, I am new to C# and working with paths the first time :(

I am using the DotNetZip Library to zip my folder ...when I try to save it it tries to save it  to programfiles/iis and gives me an error saying no permission to save it to that location.. what do i do to save it to the same directory, can some one help :(

I am doing something like

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddDirectory(Mypath);
    zip.Save("zippedfolder.zip");
}
```

I know my question is pretty simple and straight forward but I dont know how to work with it.. can someone please help me ?? am I missing something??

PS: If my question is not clear let me know I can explain again

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save it to Mypath/zippedfolder.zip:

```
zip.Save(Path.Combine(Mypath, "zippedfolder.zip"));
```

Comment: this worked fine but the zipped folder created 7 extra directories like users->name->mydocyuments->visualstudio->websites->website3->tozipfolder->zipped file

Comment: can u tell me how to zip only that without the extra directories!

Comment: Check the DotNetZip documentations. I would guess it's an option you set on the ZipFile (IncludeFolders=false or something similar)

Comment: i cant find any can u please help me with this :(

Comment: I've never used DotNetZip. Start another StackOverflow question.

Comment: i could do it :) thaks so much @zmbq

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is ASP? You need to create a folder in your web root, use `Server.MapPath("~/FolderName")` to obtain the physical path, append the name/and or path you want to go with that, and then save.

Note that your application is running under a specific identity (usually the one that also runs your IIS app pool), so that account needs to have permission to write to the directory.